# TYPO3 news system and RealURL

Tags: typo3, realurl, typo3-6.1.x

I have a little problem with the TYPO3 extension News System and Real URL.

Its not showing the urls like

```
http://codem.dk/blog/artikel/usunde_energidrikke
```

but showing it like

```
http://codem.dk/blog/artikel/?tx_news_pi1[news]=5&cHash=5370a02c0dc7e653fede425de7ac9187
```

I have added the plugin code in my realurl file, so i don't know what's wrong, and all other links which are not linking to a news are working fine.

In the Extension Manager for Real Url I have this path to the configuration file:
`typo3conf/realurl.php`

Can someone see, what's wrong here?

Im running TYPO3 v. 6.1 with FLUID/EXTBASE.

The `realurl.php` file looks like this:

```
<?php

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['addRootLineFields'].= ',tx_realurl_pathsegment';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'] = array(
        'pagePath' => array(
                'type' => 'user',
                'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
                'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                'expireDays' => '3',
                'rootpage_id' => 1,
                'firstHitPathCache'=>1
        ),
        'init' => array(
                'enableCHashCache' => TRUE,
                'enableCHashCache' => 1,
                'respectSimulateStaticURLs' => 0,
                'enableUrlDecodeCache' => 1,
                'enableUrlEncodeCache' => 1
        ),
        'preVars' => array(
                array(
                        'GETvar' => 'L',
                        'valueMap' => array(
                                'en' => '1',
                        ),
                        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ),
                array(
                        'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
                        'valueMap' => array(
                                'nc' => 1,
                        ),
                        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ),
        ),
        'fixedPostVars' => array(
                'newsDetailConfiguration' => array(
                        array(
                                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
                                'lookUpTable' => array(
                                        'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                                        'alias_field' => 'title',
                                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                                'strtolower' => 1,
                                                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                                        ),
                                        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                                        'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                                        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                                        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                                        'autoUpdate' => 1,
                                        'expireDays' => 180,
                                )
                        )
                ),
                'newsCategoryConfiguration' => array(
                        array(
                                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][categories]',
                                'lookUpTable' => array(
                                        'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_category',
                                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                                        'alias_field' => 'title',
                                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                                'strtolower' => 1,
                                                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                ),
                'newsTagConfiguration' => array(
                        array(
                                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][tags]',
                                'lookUpTable' => array(
                                        'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_tag',
                                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                                        'alias_field' => 'title',
                                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                                'strtolower' => 1,
                                                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                ),
                '52' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
                '701' => 'newsDetailConfiguration', // For additional detail pages, add their uid as well
                '71' => 'newsTagConfiguration',
                '72' => 'newsCategoryConfiguration',

        ),
        'postVarSets' => array(
                '_DEFAULT' => array(
                        'controller' => array(
                                array(
                                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
                                        'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                                ),
                                array(
                                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
                                        'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                                )
                        ),

                        'dateFilter' => array(
                                array(
                                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][year]',
                                ),
                                array(
                                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][month]',
                                ),
                        ),
                        'page' => array(
                                array(
                                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[@widget_0][currentPage]',
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
        ),

);

?>
```

(Real URL Setup in Extension-manager)
[image]

Comment: Is the RealURL auto configuration turned off?

Comment: Yes it's not "enabled" in EM, see added image in main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to edit the file **ext_localconf.php** in order to have real urls. Can you edit the file and add this code and tell me the results?

```php
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT']['postVarSets']['_DEFAULT']['action'] = array(
    array(
       'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
    ),
    array(
       'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
    ),
);

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT']['postVarSets']['_DEFAULT']['news'] = array(
    array(
        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
        'lookUpTable' => array(
            'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
            'id_field' => 'title',
            'alias_field' => 'name',
            'addWhereClause' => 'AND NOT deleted',
            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                'strtolower' => 1,
                'spaceCharacter' => '-',
             ),
             'enable404forInvalidAlias' => '1',
        ),
    )
);
```

The file is located in `root_folder/typo3conf/ext/news`.

**Note**: Remember to clear cache right after you change and save the file.

Comment: Hi Hennett, its almost working now, THX ;-) but its using the newsID as http://codem.dk/blog/artikel/news/5/ and not http://codem.dk/blog/artikel/news/usunde_energidrikke/ where is it that I changes that?

Comment: It has to do something with the **id_field** and/or the **alias_field**. I'm not sure which value you have to change, or if you have to change both. Take a look here [http://wiki.typo3.org/Realurl/manual](http://wiki.typo3.org/Realurl/manual) and search for this __->lookUpTable__. The definition table there, might give you a hint.

Comment: Hi Hennett, will u plz. add an answer. and THX

Answer (score 0):

To get title in your link instead of the uid (codem.dk/blog/artikel/news/5), change the following:

```
        'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
        'id_field' => 'uid',
        'alias_field' => 'title',
```