# realURL within News System extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I would like to have frendly URLs in news single post instead of all those hashtags, procent, question marks etc.

I have tried to follow this [article](http://www.oliver-thiele.de/cms-typo3/tutorials/realurl-konfiguration.html) but it doesn't work.

Normal pages have friendly URLs.

I am using Typo3 7.2.0 and [News System 3.2.0](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/news)

Any ideas? Thanks

**RESOLVED**

This worked [TYPO3 news system and RealURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211875/typo3-news-system-and-realurl)

Answer (score 1):

Of course that sample doesn't work as it's written for `tt_news` ext. You should use [**sample from official News' doc**](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Realurl/Index.html) instead.

Note that you can skip controller and action parts of URL by adding this to your TS:

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.link.skipControllerAndAction = 1
```

In such case you will also need to remove/comment these parts from your realurl_conf:

```
    array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
    ),
    array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks biesior, unfortunately that also doesn't work. I'll keep searching.

Comment: This has done the trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211875/typo3-news-system-and-realurl I overlooked this post earlier.

Comment: What did the trick ? sample code from linked doc is perfectly valid, just checked it, and it works as expected

Comment: Maybe, but it hasn't worked. I also have to edit ext_localconf.php in news extension folder. Now works.

Comment: you should **never** edit code of 3rd party extensions to avoid troubles after updating